# Shifting a range in ClojureScript?

Tags: range, clojurescript

How can I *shift* a range in ClojureScript ?

For example let's say we have the range:

```
(range 3)
```

Which gives: `(0 1 2)`

I'm looking for a function to shift the values to the left like this: `(1 2 0)` or like this `(2 0 1)`

I came up with an implementation which I'll share as an answer. I guess should be some built-in function to do this ? But I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I wrote:

```
(defn <-range [n l]
  (concat (drop n (range l)) (range n)))
```

A brief explanation:

- `(range l)` create a range of length l
- `(drop n)` drop n elements
- `(range n)` create a new range until n
- `(concat)` concat both the ranges

If I try:

- `(<-range 0 4)` gives `(0 1 2 3)`
- `(<-range 2 4)` gives `(2 3 0 1)`
- `(<-range 4 4)` gives `(0 1 2 3)`

Answer (score 1):

I've reversed the order of your args, as this feels closer to how `range` args work. `lazy-cat` is probably preferable to `concat`, as it won't even evaluate the second `range` until it's needed.

```
(defn <-range [length start-index]
  (lazy-cat (range start-index length)
            (range start-index)))
```

Comment: Nice. The *lazyness* works only if a function like `take` is called before `<-range` or also without using `take` ?

Comment: Yeah, it will follow all the standard laziness rules.

Answer (score 1):

there is also a `cycle` function, that (unsurprisingly) cycles a collection (to avoid the concatenation):

```
user> (defn <-range [n l]
        (->> (range l)
             cycle
             (drop n)
             (take l)))
#'user/<-range

user> (<-range 0 4)
(0 1 2 3)

user> (<-range 2 4)
(2 3 0 1)

user> (<-range 4 4)
(0 1 2 3)
```

also you can do it even without any call to `range`, based on the remainder:

```
user> (defn <-range [n l]
        (take l (iterate #(rem (inc %) l) (rem n l))))
```

or like this:

```
user> (defn <-range [n l]
        (map #(rem (+ % n) l) (range l)))
```

Comment: I also wanted to use `cycle` but I was unable to come up with an algorithm, nice one! I made a little test bench with LightTable to find out in a `1000000` range shifted by `5000` which one is the fastest. I thought your functions would be faster than using `concat` or `lazy-cat` but looks like they are from 200ms to 300ms slower. This surprised me... Instead `concat` or `lazy-cat` are mostly in the same timings around 2800-3000ms on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `range` was just used as an example and you really want to be able to do this to any collection.

```
(defn rotate-left [c]
  (lazy-cat (drop 1 c) (take 1 c)))
```

or with the ability to optionally specify more than 1 rotation,

```
(defn rotate-left
  ([c] (rot-left 1 c))
  ([n c] (lazy-cat (drop n c) (take n c))))
```

Using this,
`(rotate-left (range 3))` yields `(1, 2, 0)` and 
`(rotate-left 2 (range 3))` yields `(2, 0, 1)`